# How can I write Join without any conditions

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I want to just couple together.

```
var MenAndRandomPartners
                    = Men.Join(Partners, ..... ????
```

Comment: I don't want to know what this application does...

Comment: Do you mean a cartesian product/join?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a [CROSS JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882533.aspx), which can be accomplished with LINQ

```
var MenAndRandomPartners = 
    from man in Men
    from partner in Partners
    select new
    {
        man, partner
    };
```

You also got me curious as to how this could be written with extension methods, so here is the extension method way:

```
var MenAndRandomPartners = 
    Men.SelectMany(man => Partners, (man, partner) => new {man, partner});
```

The LINQ way is more explicit I think in this case, though...just my opinion I am sure, though

Comment: *The LINQ way is more explicit I think in this case, though.* I think the variable names are more explicit.